# Remove markers from map before adding new markers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I have a map where **initially the markers load coming from the database**, Then i have a **time based Ajax request** which gets the records again after every 1 minute.

Following is the code where i am using `setMapOnAll(null)` as from the [Google maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove), **But its not working**.

```
success: function(data){
    var positions = [];
    $.each(data.riders, function(index, value) {
        positions.push({
            lat: value.rider_location.lat,
            lng: value.rider_location.lng,
            content: value.name,
            id : value.id
        });
    });
    map.setCenter({
      lat: parseInt(positions[0].lat),
      lng: parseInt(positions[0].lng)
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker,
    i;
    setMapOnAll(null); //Remove the existing markers
    while(positions.length){
        positions.pop().setMap(null);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(positions[i].lat,positions[i].lng),
            map: map,
            id : positions[i].id,
          });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {  
        }
      }) (marker, i));
    }
  }
```

**How can i remove the existing markers before adding new ones.**

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Any errors in the console?  Where do you define the `setMapOnAll` function?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this function to your code and call it where you add new markers then add new markers. This will delete the previous markers.

```
function setMapOnAll(map) {

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

  markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

there is method marker.setMap(null) as google docs https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

you need create array of markers then remove all from map in loop by call method marker.setMap(null)

```
var markers = []; 
    for (i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(positions[i].lat,positions[i].lng),
            map: map,
            id : positions[i].id,
          });

        markers.push(marker);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {  
            }
        }) (marker, i));
    }
```

Comment: That makes sense but where should i put the code `marker.setMap(null)`. Please edit your answer.